# update all rows after insertion in mysql

Tags: mysql, trigger

I am working with mysql and I have a table with the following structure (a summary):

```
CREATE TABLE `costs` (
`id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`utility` DECIMAL(9,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`tax` DECIMAL(9,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`active` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)
```

where the active field defaults to 1 when inserting, then i would like when saving a new record all other rows update the active field as 0, so i try to create a trigger for this but i am getting a mysql error.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER after_costs_insert AFTER INSERT ON costs FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  UPDATE costs SET active = 0 WHERE id <> NEW.id;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

I think it is not possible to do this, so how can I update these rows?

Comment: Your "active" field looks like excess one - simply make `created_at` field (and maybe `updated_at` too) auto-utilized.

Answer (score 0):

Updating all rows in a table is seriously non-scalable.

Consider tossing `active` and `updated_at`.  Change `created_at` to be `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (or something like that).  And have `INDEX(created_at)`.  *Then*,

```
SELECT ...
    ORDER BY created_at DESC  LIMIT 1
```

Will get the "latest" row (which seems to be your "active").

If there is a risk of inserting two rows in the same second, there are workarounds.